# Deploy java.policy

Tags: java, security, applet, java-8

I have written some Java Applets and bundled them into a signed JAR. Even though the Applets are signed, they still need to be some changes  on the client concerning the `java.policy` file. For example, to do a print job.

To help the end user, the user can download another JAR with a small Swing app which will add the entries to their `.java.policy`.

My questions:

Is there a well known library to deploy/deliver/install `java.policy`?

The small application will simply append to the `.java.policy`. If run several time, the program will append the same data several times. It would be better if I only add the entry once. For that I have to parse the `.java.policy` and write back. Is there any library to manipulate `java.policy` entries?

Comment: Hi , I am looking for the same tools too. We want to manage hundreds of workstation to update the java.policy file. Do you have solutions today?

Answer (score 5):

Java's [Policy Tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/wstep1.html) lets you manipulate existing policy file (and even create new ones). But it's mostly geared towards developers. If you want to make it more user-friendly, I imagine you would have to write one yourself (you should be able to reuse a lot of the code from the standard policy tool).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think changing local policy files is the correct solution. Normally your applet should name the required permission level in its manifest file, e.g.:

`Permissions: all-permissions
Codebase: *
Trusted-Only: true`

More on the follwing page, see "Permissions Attribute"

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/manifest.html#A1148525

The applet needs to be signed as well.